# Using wildcards to filter out words between semantic tags with R

Tags: r, wildcard, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have a dataset that has a feature body which are all text from an html file and include semantic tags like so,

`</strong>earned six <a href="http://www.vox.com/2016/5/3/11576244/tony-award-nominations-hamilton">Tony nominations</a> this week, including one for Nyong'o (Best Actress in a Leading Role). <em>Eclipsed</em> is also significant for being the <a href="http://www.vox.com/identities/2016/5/3/11578062/eclipsed-play-tony-nomination">first Broadway play</a> to feature a cast and creative team that is entirely black, female, and of African descent. (The play was written by Danai Gurira, who also plays Michonne on <em>The Walking Dead</em>.)</p> \n<p><!--  ########  BEGIN SNIPPET  ########  -->`

I would like to remove all text between semantic tags using wildcards. Is there a way to do so?

`<!-- .-->` My logic here is to remove the comment tag with everything inside of it.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: An output dataset using R, that goes through each row and removes the semantic tag and everything in between it. In the above example, the tag is <!-- -->

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your data frame looks like this

```r
df <- data.frame(text = '</strong>earned six <a href="http://www.vox.com/2016/5/3/11576244/tony-award-nominations-hamilton">Tony nominations</a> this week, including one for Nyong\'o (Best Actress in a Leading Role). <em>Eclipsed</em> is also significant for being the <a href="http://www.vox.com/identities/2016/5/3/11578062/eclipsed-play-tony-nomination">first Broadway play</a> to feature a cast and creative team that is entirely black, female, and of African descent. (The play was written by Danai Gurira, who also plays Michonne on <em>The Walking Dead</em>.)</p> \n<p><!--  ########  BEGIN SNIPPET  ########  -->')
```

Then you could use

```r
df$new_text <- gsub("<!--.*-->", "", df$text)
```

to get your desired output in a new column `new_text`.